# How to avoid changes of columns' types in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that is composed of two columns, which are 'Time' and 'Value.'

```
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Time, Value]
Index: []

>>> df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)

>>> df.Value = df.Value.astype(float)

>>> df.Value
Series([], Name: Value, dtype: float64)

>>> df.Time
Series([], Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns])
```

What I want to do is put string data, that I recieve realtime, into the dataframe, into the dataframe without changing the columns' types. However, whenever I put data into the dataframe, their types change to object.

```
>>> data0 = '08:29:01.37543, 90.58'

>>> data0
'08:29:01.37543, 90.58'

>>> df.loc[0] = data0.split(',')

>>> df
             Time   Value
0  08:29:01.37543   90.58

>>> df.Time
0    08:29:01.37543
Name: Time, dtype: object       <--- Its type has been changed!

>>> df.Value
0     90.58
Name: Value, dtype: object      <--- Its type has been changed!
```

How can I keep their types even after adding new rows?

Comment: Don't put strings into your dataframe. Put floats and timedeltas in.

Comment: Is you question "why" or "how to avoid it"? The title and the question body seem to differ in that respect.

Comment: A man tells his doctor "it hurts when I do this".  The doctor says "don't do that".

Comment: @MSeifert My question is how to avoid it. Thank you for your recommandations! I will change the title

Answer (score 0):

After `>>> df.loc[0] = data0.split(',')` this step,

you have to change type by
`>>>df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)` and `df.Value = df.Value.astype(float)`

because you cannot insert string as float type so better way is insert data as it is string and then change the type using `astype()`

I hope this helpful.